# Nested functions in Swift

Tags: swift, nested-function

I am learning swift and want to understand how to make nested functions

```
extension Auto {
    // MARK: Auto extensions
    func isRegistred() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

if I want to verify if an Auto is registered I have to use this line
if `Auto.isRegistered()`
If the auto is registered I also want to be able to verify if it's a new one, so I want to add a `isNew()` function. Is it possible to add a nested function so that I can still verify if the auto is registered with `Auto.isRegistered()` and use `Auto.isRegistered().isNew()` to verify that it's a registered auto and a new one? Something like

```
extension Auto {
    // MARK: Auto extensions
    func isRegistred() -> Bool {
        func isNew() -> Bool{
            return true
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that wouldn't really make sense. You can't access functions within functions. `auto.isRegistered()` returns a `Bool`, so `auto.isRegistered().isNew()` would try to call the `isNew()` method on `Bool` which, obviously, doesn't exist.

I also advise you to use computed properties instead of functions if you name it "isSomething", that's more in line with Apple's APIs. So you'd get something like this:

```
extension Auto {
    var isRegistered: Bool {
        // ...
    }

    var isNew: Bool {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can simply check if an auto is both registered and new with

```
auto.isRegistered && auto.isNew
```